# Install Ruby to Ubuntu server, Should I need to create a specific user for that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, nginx, amazon-ec2

I need to deploy my Rails app to Amazon EC2 instance, I've got a **Ubuntu 14.04** 64 bit image on server.

I'm confused whether to install following packages with default user **ubuntu** or use a specific user for those for sake of **security**, also what's the norm for this kind of installation.

- Ruby
- Nginx

It'll be great if you could help me by saying whether to use specific user and which user group and also permission.

**PS: I know how to install packages as root or some user, my question is whether to use Ubuntu(default user) or some specific user with specific privilege to install and run deployment package ie, nginx.**

Comment: default user `ubuntu` or `root` ? I'm not sure now. Creating user must be the way.

Comment: To install packages you use `root`. So `sudo install...`

Comment: @Nithin : Default user is ubuntu, but for deployment and production setup what user should I use to run server that is rails and nginx.

Comment: I'm not sure but go ahead and create a user of your choice and install necessary things, that should be fine.

Comment: @Nithin : I want to know what permissions do I have grant that user so that we can ensure maximum security.